# What should be the endpoint URL when not using the Dynamo DB local?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am trying to fetch some Location Coordinates from a Dynamo DB table on a web app which are updated periodically by an android app. Since I am new to JavaScript, so I am following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Js.04.html#GettingStarted.Js.04.Scan) tutorial.

But I don't want to use local version of Dynamo DB as my table is updated by an android app & that table is not a local one. So what should be  the endpoint URL instead of *`http://localhost:8000`*.Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to remove the following lines from the config definition:

```
endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000',
accessKeyId: "fakeMyKeyId",
secretAccessKey: "fakeSecretAccessKey"
```

After that you need to set up the AWS Credentials in your local machine. You can use this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html

When the Credentials is valid, the sdk will use external tables.
You can easily test the credentials with `aws dynamodb list-tables` command.

Comment: Wow, just removing the endpoint credential in the code make it work for me. Though I didn't removed accessKeyId & secretAccessKey. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to hear :)

Answer (score 5):

Most Amazon Web Services offer a Regional endpoint that you can use to make your requests. The general syntax of a Regional endpoint is as follows.

`protocol://service-code.region-code.amazonaws.com`

For Example:

Dynamodb: `https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`

SNS: `https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

From link here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html